# Где именно я могу найти ключ API для перевода Google с помощью Python?

Tags: python, google-translate

Где именно я могу найти ключ API для перевода Google с помощью Python?

Я авторизовался на странице https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard, но есть так много вариантов и так много ключей API, что я не знаю, какой из них правильный.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше используй модуль googletrans

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
text = translator.translate('gsg', dest='ru').text
print(text)
```

Comment: конец где ключ API? Эта библиотека не принадлежит Google. это просто так называется.

Comment: @JustMe но сравните результаты. Они одинаковы.

Comment: Ну с какими результатами сравнивать? Я видел, что переводчик https://translate.google.com/ работает иначе, чем библиотека googletrans. Я много раз тестировал.

Answer (score 0):

следуйте этим шагам

https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/setup

вам нужно создать новый проект, чтобы выбрать опцию Cloud Translate...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]